# what does `size *= b - a` means?

Tags: go

I've found the following notation `size *= b - a`. I've inspected it with reflect but it seems that size is just a float64 (a,b are floats too)so my question is what is `*` for?I expected it to dereference a pointer (size) but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The operator is `*=`, not `*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know `go`, but isn't that just equal to a regular

```
size = size * (b-a)
```

Comment: I was writing this :)

Comment: You can also use `A += B` to mean `A = A + B`, `A -= B` as `A = A - B`, `A /= B` and `A %= B` (ans maybe others like `A |= B` that's equals to `A = A | B` ...)

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat feel free to accept the answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: @BartekLipinski done! I had to wait x minutes before to be able to accept it!

Answer (score 2):

`*=` is a short hand operator in go. Above line `size *= b - a` is simply equivalent to:

```
size = size * (b - a)
```

Check out *Operators and Delimiters* here: https://golang.org/ref/spec